# Convert Long to DateTime from C# Date to Java Date

Tags: java, c#, datetime, binary

I've been trying to read the binary file with Java, and the binary file is written in C#. And some of those data is contain a DateTime data.

When DateTime data will be written into the file (in binary), it using `DateTime.ToBinary();` on C#.

For reading the DateTime data, it will convert first from bytes into long data, using `BitConverter.ToInt64(byte[], 0)`, and then convert it again from long into DateTime data using `DateTime.FromBinary(long)`. (All of those are written in C#).

Let's say the long data after converting from bytes is = **-8586803256090942249**, and when convert it into DateTime, it will return = **3/17/2018 5:07:56 PM**

Now, I'm trying to read that binary file with Java. And for converting the bytes data into long data, I'm using this code : `ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[]).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong()`.

It will return the exact long data value as C# did. But when I try to convert it from long data into DateTime in Java, using `Date date = new Date(long)`, it will return = **Sun May 06 19:04:17 WIB 272097407** instead.

Can you help me what is the correct solution for this ? Is there any equivalent for `DateTime.FromBinary()` from C# in Java ? Or is my code wrong ? All of yours answers is really appreciated.

Comment: Seems there's no equivalent of `DateTime.FromBinary()` in Java libraries. However, sounds interesting to use [`DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823277(v=vs.110).aspx) and put its generated value in Java's `Date()` argument (because C# `DateTime` starts from `0001/01/01` while Java's `Date` follows Unix epoch format, i.e. from `1970/01/01`).

Comment: Can I do the opposite instead ? I mean is it possible to do with Java to convert the long data into DateTime that start from `0001/01/01` ?

Comment: Is 3/17/2018 5:07:56 PM in Western Indonesian Time too?

Comment: @imbaglia The C# part can also convert from Unix time format to `DateTime`: [`DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(millis).LocalDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds(v=vs.110).aspx). Make sure the Java code returns Unix epoch format first, then use that function to `DateTime` conversion in C# side.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes 3/17/2018 5:07:56 PM in Western Indonesian Time as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java:

```
    long fromBytes = -8586803256090942249L;

    // Mask out kind and ticks
    int kind = Math.toIntExact((fromBytes >> 62) & 0x3);
    long ticks = fromBytes & 0x3FFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFFL;
    LocalDateTime cSharpEpoch = LocalDate.of(1, Month.JANUARY, 1).atStartOfDay();
    // 100 nanosecond units or 10^-7 seconds
    final int unitsPerSecond = 10_000_000;
    long seconds = ticks / unitsPerSecond;
    long nanos = (ticks % unitsPerSecond) * 100;
    LocalDateTime ldt = cSharpEpoch.plusSeconds(seconds).plusNanos(nanos);

    switch (kind) {
    case 0: // Unspecified
    case 2: // Local time
        System.out.println("Result LocalDateTime: " + ldt);
        break;

    case 1: // UTC
        OffsetDateTime utcDateTime = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println("Result OffsetDateTime in UTC: " + utcDateTime);
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("Not a valid DateTimeKind: " + kind);
        break;
    }
```

Output:

> Result LocalDateTime: 2018-03-17T10:07:56.383355900

Edit: The number is

> A 64-bit signed integer that encodes the Kind property in a 2-bit
> field and the Ticks property in a 62-bit field.

Tetsuya Yamamoto was correct so far as the ticks property denotes number of 100-nanosecond intervals elapsed since 0001/01/01 at start of day (midnight). The kind is either 0 for unspecified, 1 for UTC or 2 for local time. So I am masking the kind and the ticks out separately.

Even though the kind is 2 in your case, which should be for local time, it seems that the time is indeed in UTC. It’s the only way that the time printed could agree with your expected 5:07:56 PM Western Indonesian Time. Maybe the number was generated on a computer with its time zone set to UTC.

To get the time in your time zone:

```
    ZoneId targetZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).withZoneSameInstant(targetZone);
    System.out.println("Converted to target time zone: " + zdt);
```

> Converted to target time zone: 2018-03-17T17:07:56.383355900+07:00[Asia/Jakarta]

This agrees with what you said you got on the C# side.

PS Avoid the `Date` class in Java if you can, it is long outdated and poorly designed and was replaced many years ago now by [*java.time*, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) (which I am of course using in the above). If you do need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, as you already noted in a comment, the conversion is like this:

```
    Instant inst = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
    Date date = Date.from(inst);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Output on a JVM with default time zone Asia/Jakarta:

> Sat Mar 17 17:07:56 WIB 2018

**Acknowledgement:** Andreas in an answer (link below) explained the structure of the 64 bits number and gave the link to the documentation. I have taken them from there.

**Links**

- [DateTime.FromBinary(Int64) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.frombinary?view=net-5.0) from the .NET documentation
- [Andreas’ answer to a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65316086/5772882)

Comment: Oh rarely using that package. What does result instant means ? It means that's date time on GMT+0 ?

Comment: Yes, the time 10:07:56 in the first line of output is in UTC. The `Z` at the end means just that (or offset zero) (the format of the output is ISO 8601).

Comment: Oh finally I can convert it that `Instant` data into date with `Date date = Date.from(instantDate);`. Thanks a lot @OleV.V.

Comment: @imbagila Yes, you can convert `Instant` to a `java.util.Date`, but do so only if you must, such as interfacing with old code not yet updated to the *java.time*. Otherwise avoid `Date`, `Calendar` and the other old legacy classes. They are entirely supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.